# Aren't "lack of specificity" and "nature of adsorbate" contradictory factors in physisorption?

Tags: adsorption

It was mentioned in my course book under "Characteristics of physisorption"  that:

> 1. Lack of specificity: An adsorbent does not show any preference for a particular gas as the van der Waal's forces are universal.
> 2. Nature of adsorbate: In general an easily liquefiable gas is more readily adsorbed as it's critical temperature is higher as van der Waal's forces are stronger near critical temperature.

Aren't these two points contradictory? If not then please explain.

Answer (score 0):

It does not show preference to any gas for chemical reasons. 
Laws of physical chemistry apply, that gas which has higher critical temperature can be easily liquefied...
It is not specific to how reactive the gas is.